# How to import dateTime literal using TTL?

Tags: datetime, sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I am copying data from one RDF store to another.

The way `dateTime` comes from the source (in XML format) is:

```
<binding name="o"><literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00</literal></binding>
```

I try to take the value as is and import it via a TTL file `myFile.ttl`:

```
<http://test.com>
    a   <http://test.com/catalog/someType> ;
    <http://test.com#modifiedDate>
        "2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00" ; # http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
    <http://test.com#numberTest>
        5 . # http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer
```

but that inserts `"2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00"` as a string. The last triple with object 5 is properly inserted as an `integer`.

How can I import `dateTime` data using TTL files? I am using `Virtuoso`. I am importing TTL files in `isql`:

```
DB.DBA.TTLP_MT(file_to_string_output('myFile.ttl'), '', 'http://my.domain.com/mygraph', 255);
```

Comment: Why are you transforming the RDF/XML to RDF-Turtle?  Virtuoso ingests both...

Comment: I was at first filtering some data from the source to apply to the target and TTL format was easier to transform the data into.  but now I just import all so i might as well take the source XML and import it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `"val" # type` format, the following worked:

```
<http://test.com>
    a   <http://test.com/catalog/someType> ;
    <http://test.com#modifiedDate>
        '2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00'^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> ;
    <http://test.com#numberTest>
        '5'^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
```

Note that even integers need to be wrapped in quotes with the `^^<type>` notation.

Comment: Turtle supports abbreviation for some numbers, e.g. `5` will be treated automatically as `xsd:integer` or `5.0` will be parsed as `xsd:decimal`

Answer (score 4):

[In Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#turtle-literals), `"2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00"` is an untyped quoted literal -- i.e., a string.

You need to have one of these instead --

- `"2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>`
- `"2016-12-01T15:31:10-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime`

As for `5` (no quotes), it isn't a quoted literal, and is a numeric string, so you got lucky with auto-typing.  Strictly speaking, the Turtle for this should probably (you didn't include the XML for this) be one of these --

- `"5"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>`
- `"5"^^xsd:integer`